# How to read spaces, words, and letters line-by-line from a file in a function using Loops (C++)

Tags: c++

so I am having a problem with getting my program to increment values properly.

My program needs to take a file in main(), and then pass that to a function-set to print that is called in main.

The key thing is that I need to use loops within the functions to get Letter Count, Space-Count, and Word Count.

I have the output configured right

```
cout << line_number << ": " << line << " [" << letter_count << " letters, " << space_count << " spaces, " << word_count << " words]" << endl;
```

Which results for example

`0: Words go here. [# letters, # spaces, # words.]`

But with my current functions for Letters and spaces, it doesn't work.

My non-space function for example

```
int count_non_space(string line) {
    int non_space = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if (line.c_str() != " ") {
            non_space++;
        }
    }
    return non_space;
```

It counts all of the characters in the line instead and the counterpart (space_count) counts nothing.

And that's not to mention that I don't know how to count the words in the line.

Any advice as to what is going on? as I am certain that count_space and count_non_space should be inverses of each other (count_space being the same function but with == instead of !=)

EDIT: Got the Letter and Space count correct.
Now, how would I get the word count from that sort of method?

EDIT 2: Okay so letter count is off.
It is counting puncutation-characters (commas, periods, dashes, hiphons.etc) as leters.

I have managed to redact periods, dashes.etc from the code manually with a reduction if statement in the count_non_characters function.

But I can't add ' to it as it already uses '' to catch the char comparison

Is there catch-all term for punctuation characters in C++ that I can use for

```
if (line[i] == "Puncutation") {
   non_space--;
}
```

?

Comment: So your goal is to count how many characters are not spaces?

Comment: `if (line.c_str() != " ")` doesn't make any sense - first of you are comparing pointers (which will never evaluate to `true`), second of you want to only compared the current character, so `if (line[i] != ' ')`

Comment: Side note: `space_count = line.length() - letter_count;` and `word_count = space_count + 1;` (Assuming no leading/trailing space or multiple spaces.)

Comment: Thank you Sheep, that did fix space and non-space tracking.
Now how would you recommend making a function to count words based on the lines?

Comment: Got it all working, thank you.

Comment: and nvm, Need letter count still off.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to count characters in a string that are not spaces, then there is a way to do this using the STL and lambdas that is much cleaner than writing a bunch of loops and worrying about updating variables.

```cpp
int count_non_space(std::string line) {
    return std::count_if(
        line.begin(), line.end(),
        [](auto ch) { 
            return ch != ' '; 
        }
    );
}
```

This also makes is very straightforward to accommodate for things like spaces *and* tabs.

```cpp
int count_non_space(std::string line) {
    return std::count_if(
        line.begin(), line.end(),
        [](auto ch) { 
            return ch != ' ' && ch != '\t'; 
        }
    );
}
```

To count the opposite (just the spaces) we simply need to change the condition in the lambda.

```cpp
int space_count(std::string line) {
    return std::count_if(
        line.begin(), line.end(),
        [](auto ch) { 
            return ch == ' ' || ch == '\t'; 
        }
    );
}
```

As Remy Lebeau helpfully points out, we don't even have to write the lambda. We can simply use the [std::isspace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) function directly instead of the lambda.

```cpp
int space_count(std::string line) {
    return std::count_if(line.begin(), line.end(), std::isspace);
}
```

Documentation on [std::count_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).

Comment: Consider using [`std::isspace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) inside your lambdas, eg: `return std::count_if(line.begin(), line.end(), [](unsigned char ch) { return !isspace(ch); });` etc

Comment: "*we don't even have to write the lambda*" - yes, you do, actually, because it is not safe to pass `char` values to `isspace()`, they need to be casted to `unsigned char`. This is explained in the `isspace()` reference I linked to.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to assist!

Answer (score 0):

As UnholySheep said, when you compare a c string (char *) you can't use standard logical operators. You will need to use strcmp(). However, if you use a c++ std::string then you can use compare() or logical operators.

As for finding words in a string. Here are a few resources.

- [c++ counting how many words in line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664964/)
- [C++ function to count all the words in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672234/)
- [C++ Program to find number of Digits and White Spaces in a String](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/09/c-program-to-find-number-of-digits-and-white-spaces-in-a-string/)
- [Count words in a given string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-words-in-a-given-string/)

For further help. Google: "Get word count per line c++"

Reminder, these two are different data types and have different library support:

- `std::string myStr`
- `myStr.c_str()`

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that, and I am using an admittedly simpler form for word counting.

But the final problem is that the letter-counting is catching punctuation characters as letters when it shouldn't,.

I feel that can be solved with a reduction of count_non_spaces as a if-loop within the function (Aka if (line[i] == "punctuation") reduce the count for non_space characters.

But I don't know if there is a catch-all for that in C++ or not as I don't know how to add things like hyphons to a "or" version of that if loop as I already use '' in the loop to compare against

Comment: I would look into using a regex to filter out undesired characters. "C++ Regex to remove punctuation"

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would revise the function you gave:

```cpp
int count_non_space(string line) {
    int non_space = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if (line[i] != ' ') {
            non_space++;
        }
    }
    return non_space;
}
```

Notes:

- I changed `line.c_str()` to `line[i]` in order to access the `i`th character of `line`
- I changed `" "` to `' '` so that it's comparing against the space `char`, not a `string` which only contains the space. The comparison would fail if we were comparing the `i`th char to a `string`

---

As for this:

> And that's not to mention that I don't know how to count the words in the line.

I don't know how your requirements define a word, but if we assume a word is any contiguous clump of non-space characters, you could use this logic:

1. initialize `bool in_word` to `false`
2. initialize `int word_count` to `0`
3. for each `char` in the `string`:

   1. if `in_word` is `false` and the current `char` is **not** a space, then set `in_word` to be `true` and increase `word_count` by 1
   2. if `in_word` is `true` and the current `char` **is** a space, then set `in_word` to be `false`
4. return `word_count`

Comment: I did follow with that, and I have a way for word counts that seems to work well enough.

But my letter counting seems to be catching punctuation characters in it when it shouldn't (periods, parenthesis, commas, hyphens).

I assume I should do a reduction if statement inside the function to account for that but I don't know if there is a catch-all for punctuation terms that can be applied in that way for C++

Comment: So you're talking about trying to count the number of letters?
If you `#include <cctype>` you can use the `isalpha` function to determine if a char is alphabetic or not: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/